# Using Bonferroni’s inequality to prove the following:

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $A_k(1\leqslant k \leqslant \infty)$ be events from sample space $\Omega$, such that $P(A_k)=1 (1\leqslant k \leqslant \infty)$.

Prove that: $P(\bigcap \limits _{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}) = 1$

I was wondering how to prove with only $P(\bigcap \limits _{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}) = 1$ instead of $\geqslant 1$.

Comment: I suspect you want $1\leqslant k \lt \infty$ rather than $1\leqslant k \leqslant \infty$

Comment: No probability can be grater than $1$ or less than $0$.  So $P\left(\bigcup \limits _{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}^c\right)=0$ and $P\left(\bigcap \limits _{k=1}^{\infty}A_{k}\right) = 1$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bonferroni's inequality immediately implies that a countable union of events with probability $0$ also has probability $0$. Thus $\mathbb{P}(\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n^c)=0$, and so the probability of the complement $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is $1$. You really don't need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is noting that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cup B)$, and so the intersection of two events with probability one has probability 1 as well. By induction any finite intersection of such events also has probability 1. Now consider $B_n=\cap_{k=1}^n A_k$, which is a decreasing sequence of events such that $\cap_{n=1}^\infty A_n = \cap_{n=1}^\infty B_n$, and $P(\cap_{n=1}^\infty B_n) =1$ by continuity from above of $P$.

Comment: But we are asked to use Bonferroni’s inequality to prove.